# Maven shade plugin - don't relocate excluded/optional scope dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using maven shade plugin in order to create an uber jar while relocating all classes. That's because I'm getting an external jar and I don't want to have classpath collisions. So the idea is to create a new uber (relocated) jar and use it in my application.
So the shade plugin takes all the classes and relocates them to the new package prefix. My issue is that a far as I understand, it also does that for dependencies which the classes they depend on, aren't in the scope [*].

Let's say I'm relocating all `com` to `shade.com`:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>rename-all</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
      <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
        <relocations>
          <relocation>
            <pattern>com</pattern>
            <shadedPattern>shade/com</shadedPattern>
          </relocation>
        </relocations>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

So if one of my dependencies, A, has a `<optional>` dependency on B (which package `com.B`), the plugin would change the imports within A to point to `shade.com.B`. But com.B is optional, which means those classes won't be available in `shade.com.B`, because they didn't get into the relocation process. The actual classes available when using this jar would be the "normal" ones - `com.B`.
And then I get class not found exceptions on `shade.com.B` classes when I try to use the shaded jar in my application.

Am I missing something in my understanding? Is there any solution to this?

[*] Some examples: I'm not sure yet about the exact cases where this happens. In my case, I depend on `spark-sql`dependency. I dig into 3 of the classes which I saw this issue (there are many more):

1. `org/apache/html/dom/HTMLIsIndexElementImpl` imports `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLIsIndexElement` which is in `rt.jar` - the import was relocated so now it points to `shade.org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLIsIndexElement` and can't be found.
2. `io/netty/handler/codec/marshalling/ChannelBufferByteOutput` imports `org.jboss.marshalling.ByteOutput`. Hence the relocation change this to `import shade.org.jboss.marshalling.ByteOutput`. But as can be seen [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty/3.9.9.Final/netty-3.9.9.Final.pom), the import for `jboss-marshalling` is marked as `<optional>true</optional>`, so it's not in the jar and `ByteOutput` itself won't be relocated, hence won't be available.
3. `jasper-runtime` is included [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.6.5/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.5.pom) but excluded in the upper one, [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.6.5/hadoop-client-2.6.5.pom). So the outcome is that the files in Hadoop-hdfs are getting relocation to their dependencies, even though these classes would never be available in the relocated path since they aren’t in the jar at all. e.g. `org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/browseBlock_jsp` now has a reference to “shade/org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceDependent”.

Comment: have you checked that how? `My issue is that a far as I understand, it also does that for dependencies in <provided> scope.`? Apart from that usually using shaded jar's in applications is a really bad idea cause it produces issues in several way (you can't exclude etc.) and can not use the usual dependency mechanism which is really bad. My suggestion is: Only use shade to create executables but never for reusable artifacts... If your external jar is the problem fix that?.... otherwise it will cause more issues than you think / and like to have...

Comment: I took the shaded jar and checked the compiled classes. I can see the imports. I've edited my question in order to provide some examples. Indeed, so far I didn't find an example with the `provided` scope - but I randomly chose 3 classes and checked why they fail, each one with different reason.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using the shaded jar as a pluggable jar for my application, the purpose is to bring it in and avoid possible class path collisions, hence the shading and uber jar.

Comment: You can of course do what you like but I strongly recommend not to do that...because it will produce error/problems in the future...

Comment: Could you a little elaborate on which kind of problems? Assuming that I (successfully) shade the jar.